# Using UITabBarController in a subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a view in my app to which I want to add tabs, but only in the lower half of the view. The top half of this view is supposed to be fixed. Something like this:

[image]

By pressing the tabs on that UITabBar I want to toggle the contents of the lower half, but without changing the contents of the upper half. I used tab bars before with UITabBarController, but using storyboard I can't add the controller because it creates two completely different views. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using UIContainerView?

Comment: No. What is that? I can't find the docs.

Comment: Have a look at http://goo.gl/AnOLpY